# Scrolling performance

Tags: html, performance, css, scroll

I have an example that contains some elements. When i scroll so fast elements not showing and slowly loaded. Is this bug or any other problem ?
My html structure:

```
<div class="site-header">
  This is site header  
</div>
<div class="site-content">
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item-container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image-container">

        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <span>Hello World</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- End of content -->
```

I created a example. Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/Shuree/pen/OQPJPx). You need to check it with a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bug. When you are trying to laod image in browser, for the first time, the browser will cache the image for faster laoding in next time. So for the first time it will take some time. If you want to load it faster try to use small size with good pixel ratio image **(i.e compressed)** , it will load faster when compared to normal one.

If you want read more about browser caching use this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching). 
Use Chrome lighthouse to check the static data performance(i.e images), [check here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/).
let me know if this works